# How to mock objects in C# using Visual Studio Unit Testing framework or NUnit framework?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, mocking, nunit

I have moved to developing applications in C# from Java. I came across the Visual Studio unit testing framework provided by Visual Studio, and another framework called NUnit.

1. Which of these frameworks support mocking objects, or something similar to returning specific response to a method in another project whose source code is not available?

I'm using Visual Studio Pro, so Microsoft Fakes is not applicable to me. Also, I came across moq, and rhinomocks but I'm not sure about these.

2. I was wondering if I can use a unit testing framework like the one provided by Visual Studio or NUnit without having to add additional dependency.

Comment: Note that the title doesn’t really match the question and asking for software recommendations is off topic here.

Comment: _"...mocking...whose `source code` is not available..."_ - you **don't** need the AUT's source code in order to test it.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I have changed the title and body. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three popular unit testing frameworks used to support unit testing (Microsft `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools`, `NUnit` and `xUnit`) and none of them supports mocking.

From my experience, `moq` works quite well for most projects. For the example of how to use it in practice check this project [DjvuNet](https://github.com/DjvuNet/DjvuNet). There you will find multiple examples of simple and complex mocking scenarios. This particular project uses xUnit as a unit test framework but it does not have any impact on how mocking is done.